# Can I use verb "to split" in meaning to "to run"?

Tags: idioms, synonyms

There is [an idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/time+to+split) "time to split" which means "time to run", "time to go away".

But can I use verb "split" separately with the same meaning? For example
"They have split and stopped responding me.".

Comment: Do you mean to say that they have gone away from the place where you are, and that is why they have stopped responding **to** you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Split* in this sense ordinarily designates literal physical departure, not figurative "departure" from a discussion or negotiation. It does not have the connotation of flight suggested by "run away" or the connotation of evasion which seems to be implied by the scenario you describe. It's most often used in the first person: *We split and went to find a bar*, *Let's split this popsicle stand*.

*Split* in this sense is colloquial only; you should not use it in more formal contexts. It's 1960s slang, and its use today tends to be somewhat ironic.

Comment: "They split" can also mean a couple ended their relationship, so with 'they' in particular it can be a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Also worth noting that the register is usually low enough that "they have split" sounds incongruous.